# Unable to pass data to View Controller embedded in nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do something this:
[image]

I want to pass some data to ApplicationsViewController which is embedded in nav bar, therefore I get the error: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'

I am not able to understand how to implement the same. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add code in screen shot as "Text" in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you can't pass data directly to `ApplicationViewController` as `InboxViewController` segue's destination is `UINavigationController`.

So, first you need to access `UINavigationController` and after that `ApplicationsViewController` from the stack.

Try the code below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToApplications" {
        if let navigation = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let applicationVC = navigation.topViewController as? ApplicationsViewController {
            applicationVC.id = "RGB"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when pass data application view controller which is rootviewController of UINavigationController. you should give segue name of navigation controler and type cast as UINavigationController as destination viewcontroller. 
Fetch rootviewController which is application View controller and assign value of id

Here is code how to assign value to Application ViewController

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "navigationSegue" {  // segue of navigationVC
            let navVc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let appVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! ApplicationsViewController
            appvc.id = "RGB"
        }
    }
```